# Symmetry eliminates degrees of freedom

Tags: rotational-dynamics, symmetry, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

Consider a system of $n$ particles, such as isolated atoms, molecules, nuclei, and the solar system, with $3n$ degrees of freedom; why does translational invariance eliminate three degrees of freedom and rotational invariance eliminate two degrees of freedom for this system?

Comment: Are you interested in point particles, i.e. a system where the rotation of each individual particle doesn't matter? This would make sense because otherwise $3n$ wouldn't be the number of degrees of freedom (DOF). But, also, in that case I think the statement is false: For $n=1$ this is easy to see - you can't take away five DOF when there are only three - for $n=2$ it's correct and for $n>2$ rotation should take away three DOF if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

To explain my comment above:

If you have just one particle, it can be described by its position $\vec{x} = (x,y,z)$, three degrees of freedom (DOF). But if the system is invariant under translation the position doesn't matter and no DOF are left.

If you add a second particle, the system has six DOF, the positions of both particles $\vec{x}_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $\vec{x}_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$. If the system is invariant under translation, we lose three DOF because it suffices to specify the position of one particle relative to the other, i.e. $\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_2$. If you also add invariance under rotation the only DOF left is the distance between the particles. (I.e. for $n=2$ particles there is 1 DOF.)

Now, keeping the assumption of invariance under translation and rotation, when adding a third particle (at $\vec{x}_3$) you specify its position via its distance to the first particle and the angle between $\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_2$ and $\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_3$, i.e. we gain only two DOF and the system of $n=3$ particles has 3 DOF.

And then for every further particle we add we gain three DOF.

A more technical answer for $n>2$ would be that the system is invariant under a transformation
$$
\vec{x} \rightarrow \vec{x}' = A \vec{x} + \vec{a}
$$
with $A \in SO(3)$. Because the translation vector $\vec{a}$ has three dimensions we lose three DOF for translation and because [$SO(3)$ is three-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813634/why-so3-mathbbr-is-3-dimensional) we lose three DOF for the invariance under rotation.